# Asynchronous event handling in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an issue with preventing double (multiple) `eventListener` handling in code:

```
var locked;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    calculateSomethingHeavy();
    locked = false;
}
```

Second immediate button click triggers another event, despite `locked == true`. Things like `button.disabled = true` or `setTimeout(function() {locked = true;}, 0)` have no effect because (I guess) second call is stacked and will be invoked only after first is fully handled. I think I'm missing some whole technology of asynchronous event handling. How to do this in pure js?

Comment: Is `calculateSomethingHeavy` *heavy* or *asynchronous* (or both)? Those are very distinct concepts

Comment: If `calculateSomethingHeavy` is meant to be asynchronous and you need `locked` to be set to false after it completes, then you need to return a Promise from `calculateSomethingHeavy` and set locked to false in its success handler.  As written, this is synchronous code, so locked will be set to false immediately after `calculateSomethingHeavy` is called.

Comment: Actually, `calculateSomethingHeavy` is a bit tricky - the function fills a big canvas with pixels and after its first call it timeouts itself 99 more times to give some time for refreshing progress bars on the page (so each function call does 1% of all calculations). But the thing is, `eventListener` behaviour doesn't depend on existence of those timeouts, so I put simplified version here (I hope solution also doesn' depend on that)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The correct answer here depends on the definition of `calculateSomethingHeavy`. Presumably it's asynchronous based on the question title, but that could be implemented using callbacks, or events, or promises or async/await.

Regardless of which of those is at play here, what you need to do is ensure that `locked` is not set to `false` until after `calculateSomethingHeavy` has finished.
That might look like the following in each case...

### Callbacks

```
var locked;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    calculateSomethingHeavy(() => {
        locked = false;
    });
});
```

### Events

```
var locked;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    calculateSomethingHeavy().on('finish', () => {
        locked = false;
    });
});
```

### Promises

```
var locked;

button.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    calculateSomethingHeavy()
        .then(() => {
            locked = false;
        });
});
```

### async/await

```
var locked;

button.addEventListener("click", async function() {
    if (locked) return;
    locked = true;
    await calculateSomethingHeavy();
    locked = false;
});
```

Comment: I just want to pose a question, what value does setting the `locked = false` in an asynchronous call? Even if you wanted to access `locked` in the outside global scope, it would still have it's original value...even though the event (and async call) has fired. Out of curiosity, is there any way to set globals in async calls and read thew new values in the outside scope?

Comment: @JabariDash, the value is in the `if` test at the top of the event handler. It is there to prevent re-entrancy, so if `calculateSomethingHeavy` is already calculating, the function becomes a NOP instead of calling it again.