# Event Handling in Javascript using buttons

Tags: javascript, eventhandler

I have two functions that have if statements inside them. I am trying to choose which function to run based off which keys are pressed. When ran the keys without shift override the shift if statements. I am sure to solve this an event handler should be used. However I am not sure where to even start. If the standard ifs are taken out the shift if statements work and vice versa.

Individually each function works as intended. I have looked into adding an event handler based off what is pressed which function overrides which. I have looked at [Event Handing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51235702/asynchronous-event-handling-in-javascript) and not really sure where to begin.

```
var map = {};
onkeydown = onkeyup = function(e){
    e = e || event; //deals with IE Compatibility
    map[e.key] = e.type == 'keydown';
}
```

I have an array that maps the keys that are pressed since there are more than one key that can be pressed at a specific time.

```
document.onkeydown = function (e){
    if(e.which == 16 && e.which == 117){ //ShiftF6
        try {
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click();
            console.log("Button clicked.");
        } catch(ex) {
        };
        try {
            // eslint-disable-line prefer-template
            document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name=bugnote_text]")[0].value = //display text
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Close Ticket']")[0].click();
            console.log("Button clicked.");
        } catch(ex) {
        };
}
```

This is an example of what is being done with shift and a simple function key.

```
document.onkeydown = function(zEvent){
    if(zEvent.which == 117){ //F6
    try {
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value=Close]")[0].click();
            console.log("Button clicked.");
        } catch(ex) {
        };
        try {
            // eslint-disable-line prefer-template
            document.querySelectorAll("textarea[name=bugnote_text]")[0].value = //Display text;
            document.querySelectorAll("input[value='Close Ticket']")[0].click();
            console.log("Button clicked.");
        } catch(ex) {
        };
    }
```

This is just a single button press.

Note there are multiple if statements inside each function no more than 5 in each however. I know placing these statements in a switch or array would probably be cleaner. I am trying to just decide which function to work out of depending which buttons are being pressed.  I am not sure where to begin to get it to choose which way to go.

Comment: not very clear.

Comment: The `e.which == 16 && e.which == 117` condition will never be true. The `which` property can't be two numbers at once.

Comment: ^ Elaborating on what Bergi mentioned, pressing `SHIFT + F6` would fire *two* `onkeydown` events: one where `e.which === 16` and another where `e.which === 117`. Instead, in your `F6` event, you can check `e.which === 117 && e.shiftKey`.